# How to run command for several files in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, image-processing

I have a folder with images and I need to convert them using ImageMagick . How to run command for each file (as parameter) in Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficiency's sake (since I can see you're on `v4` by your use of the array `ForEach` method), you can use the `-File` switch on `Get-ChildItem` (introduced in `v3`) and only get the files you need.  Additionally, using the `foreach` keyword is more readable and performant than either `.ForEach()` or `ForEach-Object`.

You can use the call operator to run external executables (`&`):

```
$magick = 'C:\INSTALL\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\magick.exe'

$path = 'C:\Pictres'
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File) {
    & $magick "$($file.FullName)" -negate "$path\test_$($file.Name)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Get-ChildItem` returns an array of [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) objects and you should not treat them as simply string that hold the path and file name.
Instead, use the properties of these objects `FullName` and `Name`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Pictres" -File | ForEach-Object {
    # The automatic variable '$_' or '$PSItem' contains the current object in the PowerShell pipeline.
    $originalImage  = $_.FullName
    $convertedImage = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath ('test_{0}' -f $_.Name)
    & 'C:\INSTALL\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\magick.exe' "$originalImage" -negate "$convertedImage"
}
```

Comment: It also returns `DirectoryInfo` which has a different behavior from `FileInfo`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 True, but not as in the code when using the `-File` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Get-ChildItem` and `ForEach`. `$PSItem` is defined automatically

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Pictres").ForEach({
 >> $BuildName = "C:\Pictres\$PSItem"
 >> $BuildName2 = "C:\Pictres\test_$PSItem"
 >> C:\INSTALL\ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16\magick.exe "$BuildName" -negate "$BuildName2"
 >> }
 >> )
```

Comment: Please do not post the missing details of your question as answer. Instead, [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56147091/edit) and put the code you use in there. Next, delete this answer.

Comment: Actually, I have asked question, and after doing some research quickly found answer. So I have answered my own question. I shall accept this answer in 2 days.